# concatenate lists in a list by comparing first element Python

Tags: python, list

I need a function or code to concatenate some lists in a list. I searched here in this site for a solution but I didn't find a suitable one with my need, also I tried many solutions without result.

I have this example from my code:

the list is:

```
[['He', 'is', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]],
['is', 'angry.', [0, 1]],
 ['is', 'happy.', [2, 3]],
 ['is', 'sleep.', [4]],
 ['angry.', 'He', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]],
 ['happy.', 'He', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]],
 ['going.', 'He', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]],
 ['sleep.', 'He', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]],
 ['sad.', 'He', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]]
```

I need to group the lists that have same first value e.g. by 'is' the output should be like:

```
[['He', 'is', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]],
 ['is', ['angry.',' happy.', 'sleep.'], [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4]]],
 ['angry.', 'He', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]],
 ['happy.', 'He', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]],
 ['going.', 'He', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]],
 ['sleep.', 'He', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]],
 ['sad.', 'He', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]]
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Believe you have a typo on line 2 of your suggested output. Possibly missing closing bracket if that's what you intended ?

Comment: yes you are true, thanks. I edited and I think it is clear now. It is ONE BIG LIST has lists inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `itertools.groupby` to group the list with first value of inner list, then zip the group data and merge them, like this:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
source = [['He', 'is', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]],
['is', 'angry.', [0, 1]],
 ['is', 'happy.', [2, 3]],
 ['is', 'sleep.', [4]],
 ['angry.', 'He', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]],
 ['happy.', 'He', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]],
 ['going.', 'He', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]],
 ['sleep.', 'He', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]],
 ['sad.', 'He', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]]
groups = groupby(source, itemgetter(0))
result = []
for key,data in groups:
    list_data = list(data)
    if len(list_data) == 1:
        result.append(list_data[0])
    elif len(list_data) >1:
        zip_data = zip(*list_data) # list(zip(*list_data)) for python 3
        result.append([key]+[list(zip_data[1])]+[list(zip_data[2])])
```

`result` will be:

```
[['He', 'is', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]],
 ['is', ['angry.', 'happy.', 'sleep.'], [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4]]],
 ['angry.', 'He', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]],
 ['happy.', 'He', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]],
 ['going.', 'He', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]],
 ['sleep.', 'He', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]],
 ['sad.', 'He', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]]
```

Comment: it gives this error: TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable for this line:result.append([key]+[list(zip_data[1])]+[list(zip_data[2])]), I am using python 3.6

Comment: Yes it works by editing the line zip_data = zip(*list_data) to zip_data = list(zip(*list_data))

Comment: @NujudAli you are right, this is for python 2, I have updated it for python 3 based on your finding :)